# Independent chances of $3$ events ${a\over{a+x}}$, ${b\over{b+x}}$, ${c\over{c+x}}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Here's a problem from my probability textbook:

> Of three independent events the chance that the first *only* should happen is *a*; the chance of the second *only* is $b$; the chance of the third *only* is $c$. Show that the independent chances of the three events are respectively$${a\over{a+x}}, \quad {b\over{b+x}}, \quad {c\over{c+x}},$$where $x$ is a root of the equation$$(a+x)(b+x)(c+x) = x^2.$$

Here's what I did. We have$$a = p_1(1 - p_2)(1 - p_3), \quad b = (1-p_1)p_2(1-p_3), \quad c = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_3.$$Without loss of generality let's consider $a$. We have$$p_1 = {a\over{(1 - p_2)(1 - p_3)}}.$$If we assume the result we want to show, then this equals$$p_1 = {a\over{\left(1 - {b\over{b+x}}\right)\left(1 - {c\over{c+x}}\right)}} = {a\over{{{x^2}\over{(b+x)(c+x)}}}} = {a\over{a+x}}.$$However, we assumed in part what we wanted to show, which possibly makes this circular.

Another observation I noticed is that$$p_1p_2p_3 + p_1p_2(1-p_3) + p_1(1-p_2)p_3 + (1-p_1)p_2p_3 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3) + a + b + c = 1.$$However, despite what I've tried, I'm stuck and do not know how to proceed further. Could anybody help me? Is there a way to turn my circular approach into a noncircular one?

Comment: Hint: think about what $x$ should be as an expression of $p_1, p_2, p_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}a&=&p(1-q)(1-r)\\b&=&(1-p)q(1-r)\\c&=&(1-p)(1-q)r\end{array}$$

(where $p,q,r$ are the probabilities of those events. I prefer to use $p,q,r$ rather than $p_1, p_2, p_3$ - for the ease of typing!)

Now, let $x=(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)$ - the probability that *none* of the events happened. Then, obviously:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{a}{a+x}&=&\frac{p(1-q)(1-r)}{p(1-q)(1-r)+(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)}\\&=&\frac{p(1-q)(1-r)}{(1-q)(1-r)}\\&=&p\end{array}$$

and similarly for $q$ and $r$. Moreover:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}(a+x)(b+x)(c+x)&=&(1-q)(1-r)\cdot(1-p)(1-r)\cdot(1-p)(1-q)\\&=&(1-p)^2(1-q)^2(1-r)^2\\&=&x^2\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks @Stinking Bishop. How did you get "Now, let $x = (1 - p)(1 - q)(1 - r)$..."? That step feels like magic to me. Of course one can check it works, but it feels unmotivated i.e. you pulled that out of nowhere.

Comment: @EmperorConcerto I was part-drawing Venn diagrams and part-thinking "What can $x$ be?" Call the events $A,B,C$. $A$ is independent on $B$ and $C$, so $p=P(A)=P(A|\lnot B\land\lnot C)$ (*conditional probability* involved here!), i.e. I can see $P(A)=\frac{P(A\land\lnot B\land\lnot C)}{P(\lnot B\land \lnot C)}$. The numerator there is $a$, and if you draw the Venn diagram you will see exactly what the denominator is, and where this particular $x$ comes from.

Comment: Thanks, could you edit this in and write it out more in detail? It is still not so clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you want $p_1=\frac{a}{a+x}$. Since $a=p_1(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$, then $a+x=(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$. You can further simplify $x=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$. This satisfies the equation in the question.

Comment: Thanks @sankhya, and welcome to Math Stack Exchange! How did you get $a + x = (1-p_2)(1-p_3)$ from $a = p_1(1 - p_2)(1-p_3)$? I do not follow that step.

Comment: You were asked to show that $p_1=\frac{a}{a+x}$. Since $a=p_1(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$, you can figure out $x$.

Answer (score 1):

To get corner cases out of the way, if $p_1=1$ then $b=c=0$, and $x=1-a$ will satisfy all the wanted properties. If $p_1=0$, then $a=0$ and the problem reduces to a similar one with only two events. The same goes for $p_2$ and $p_3$, so from here on assume $0<p_1<1$, $0<p_2<1$, and $0<p_3<1$.

From your observation

$$a = p_1(1 - p_2)(1 - p_3), \quad b = (1-p_1)p_2(1-p_3), \quad c = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_3$$

we can get

$$ (1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3) = \frac{1-p_1}{p_1} a = \frac{1-p_2}{p_2} b = \frac{1-p_3}{p_3} c $$

If we call this value $x = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$, then $x>0$ and

$$ x = \frac{1-p_1}{p_1} a $$
$$ \frac{x}{a} = \frac{1}{p_1} - 1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{p_1} = \frac{a+x}{a} $$
$$ p_1 = \frac{a}{a+x} $$

Solving for $p_2$ and $p_3$ works just the same.

To show that $(a+x)(b+x)(c+x) = x^2$, it will be easier to look at the left side divided by $x^3$:

$$ \begin{align*} \frac{(a+x)(b+x)(c+x)}{x^3} &= \left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right) \left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right) \left(1+\frac{c}{x}\right) \\
 &= \left(1+\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\right) \left(1+\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}\right) \left(1+\frac{p_3}{1-p_3}\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)} = \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*} $$

Now just multiply both sides by $x^3$ to get the polynomial equation in the question.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler. How did you get "If we call this value $x = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$..."? That step feels like magic to me. Of course one can check it works, but it feels unmotivated i.e. you pulled that out of nowhere.

Comment: @EmperorConcerto Calling it $x$ is cheating a bit, yes. At that point, we just know it's something with a simple relation to the other variable pairs. Instead I could call it $q$, solve for $p_1$, and discover that the $x$ the problem is looking for happens to be exactly $x=q$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $(a+x)(b+x)(c+x)=x^2$

$\implies (a+\alpha)(b+\alpha)(c+\alpha)=\alpha^2$

Now, $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ satisfies the system of equations

$\begin{align}
(1) \quad p_1(1 - p_2)(1 - p_3) = a \\
(2) \quad (1-p_1)p_2(1-p_3) = b \\
(3) \quad (1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_3 = c
\end{align}$

It's sufficient to show that $\left(\frac{a}{a+\alpha},\frac{b}{b+\alpha}, \frac{c}{c+\alpha}\right)$ satisfies the above system of equations.

$(1) \quad \frac{a}{a+\alpha}\left(1 - \frac{b}{b+\alpha}\right)\left(1 - \frac{c}{c+\alpha}\right)=\frac{a}{a+\alpha}.\frac{\alpha}{b+\alpha}.\frac{\alpha}{c+\alpha}= \frac{a.\alpha^2}{(a+\alpha)(b+\alpha)(c+\alpha)} = \frac{a.\alpha^2}{\alpha^2}=a, \quad$ assuming $\alpha \neq 0$

$(2) \quad \left(1 - \frac{a}{a+\alpha}\right)\frac{b}{b+\alpha}\left(1 - \frac{c}{c+\alpha}\right)=\frac{\alpha}{a+\alpha}.\frac{b}{b+\alpha}.\frac{\alpha}{c+\alpha}= \frac{b.\alpha^2}{(a+\alpha)(b+\alpha)(c+\alpha)} = \frac{b.\alpha^2}{\alpha^2}=b, \quad$ assuming $\alpha \neq 0$

$(3) \quad \left(1 - \frac{a}{a+\alpha}\right)\left(1 - \frac{b}{b+\alpha}\right)\frac{c}{c+\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{a+\alpha}.\frac{\alpha}{b+\alpha}.\frac{c}{c+\alpha}= \frac{c.\alpha^2}{(a+\alpha)(b+\alpha)(c+\alpha)} = \frac{c.\alpha^2}{\alpha^2}=c, \quad$ assuming $\alpha \neq 0$

Comment: Thanks @Sandipan Dey. How is your answer not circular? It seems you are assuming what we want to show with assuming $p_1 = {a\over{a + \alpha}}$, $p_2 = {b\over{b + \alpha}}$, $p_3 = {c\over{c + \alpha}}$.

Comment: @EmperorConcerto we want to show if $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial, then $\left(\frac{a}{a+\alpha}, \frac{b}{b+\alpha}, \frac{c}{c+\alpha}\right)$ solves the system of equations (1)-(3). Now, we also know that ($p_1, p_2, p_3$) solves the system of equations, it means they can be chosen to be as $\left(\frac{a}{a+\alpha}, \frac{b}{b+\alpha}, \frac{c}{c+\alpha}\right)$.